# Creating a trigger with WHERE clause to a table

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I started SQLite yesterday and trying stuff. I searched google and stackoverflow for an answer but couldn't find any :( I've created a database and inside that created a few tables *income* and *expense*. Then I've inserted 20 entries and tried to make a trigger to log any changes done to entries between 5 - 10. But an error message comes `Error: near "where": syntax error`

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE expense(
...> ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
...> Category text,
...> Amount real
...> );

sqlite> CREATE TABLE logger(
...> ID int,
...> Time text
...> );

sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER UPDATE OF amount ON expense WHERE ID BETWEEN 5 AND 10;
...> BEGIN
...> INSERT INTO logger(ID, time) VALUES(new.ID, datetime('now'));
...> END;
```

Why doesn't `WHERE` working? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In defining triggers in SQLite you should use `WHEN` instead of `WHERE`. Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log AFTER UPDATE OF amount ON expense 
FOR EACH ROW WHEN new.ID BETWEEN 5 AND 10
BEGIN
INSERT INTO logger(ID, time) VALUES(new.ID, datetime('now'));
END;
```

Note also that I added `FOR EACH ROW`. It is optional for now in SQLite, but it is useful for documentation.

Comment: Wow it worked! :D Thanks @Renzo That tutorial I'm using doesn't even have that 'WHEN' keyword. Thanks for the support \m/